# Is there any way to alternate between two values in python

Tags: python, alternating

Suppose I have a value say `Player 1` and  `Player 2`. Can I assign them to a single variable in such a way such that

```
print("%s choose this piece" %Player_value)
```

Expected output

```
Player 1 choose this value
Player 2 choose this value
```

How can this be done!

Please help!

Comment: No, there's no way to make that happen automatically. You need to reassign `Player_value` before each `print()`

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you want to happen here; do you want all of that output from a single `print`?  If so, you need to look up how to make a print format iterate through a list of values.

Comment: @Prune I think he actually means successive prints alternate.

Comment: Yeah @Prune Barmar is right

Comment: See [How much research?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).  I suggest that you do your research: see how others have implemented alternating between players.  This is not yet a Stack Overflow question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```py
>>> import itertools
>>> player = itertools.cycle(['Player 1', 'Player 2'])
>>> print("%s choose this piece" % next(player))
Player 1 choose this piece
>>> print("%s choose this piece" % next(player))
Player 2 choose this piece
>>> print("%s choose this piece" % next(player))
Player 1 choose this piece
...
```

Comment: This is a very elegant solution, but it has the downside that you can't fetch the player number after you have printed it.  You're usually going to need to answer the musical question "whose turn is it?  more than once.

Comment: `File "/home/nimm.py", line 9, in main
    player = itertools.cycle(['Player 1', 'Player 2'])
NameError: name 'itertools' is not defined`

This is happening

Comment: That's probably a good point, but wasn't included in the question so I didn't address it. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @KaryonTrotters Don't skip this part: `import itertools`

Comment: @Woodford oh yeah lol sorry I missed it out thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of good ways to do this kind of swap.  An easy way is to use integers, 1 and 2.  The swap then becomes:

```
    Player_value = 3 - Player_value
```

Another way is to have a list.  This is overkill for two, but allows for more than two.

```
    Players = [1, 2]
    print("Player %d choose:" % Players[0] )
    Players.append( Players.pop(0) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a dictionary, and iterate through that. Keys are the player name and values are player values.

```
playerDict = {"Player1":"10","Player2":"20"}
for players in playerDict:print(f"{players} choose this {playerDict[players]}")
```

**output**

```
Player1 choose this 10
Player2 choose this 20
```

Answer (score 0):

Code :

```
value=0
value = abs(value-1)
print(value)
```

Output :

```
0
1
0
1
```

if you want to use player A and B :

```
player=["A","B"]
value = 0
value = abs(value - 1)
print("player "+player[value])
```

Result :

```
player A
player B
player A
player B
```

Comment: This is a nice trick for 0 and 1 but what if we're not dealing with integers? What if we're dealing with "Player A" and "Player B"? What if we have 3 players?

Comment: @SolarBear yes of course this won't work with 3 players but with player A and B you can use this method, it's just a bit longer